# BASH search for multiple IP's in table

Tags: bash, search, while-loop

This is a continuation of a script I got help on a few weeks ago. I got everything working, unfortunately the scenario has changed a bit and I'm under a little pressure to get this up and running so I was hoping someone here would help me quickly modify this script.

Here are the basics. The purpose of the script is to recapture a specific floating IP. Due to system limitations, the only way to do this currently is by kinda playing the lottery... The script requests a pool of floating IP's and puts them in a table that looks like this:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+
| Ip         | Server Id | Fixed Ip | Pool          |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+
| 10.10.10.1 |           | -        | floating-pool |
| 10.10.10.2 |           | -        | floating-pool |
| 10.10.10.3 |           | -        | floating-pool |
| 10.10.10.4 |           | -        | floating-pool |
| 10.10.10.5 |           | -        | floating-pool |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+
```

The script then checks to see if the floating IP we are looking for is in that table, ie has been captured. If not, the script returns all IP's back to the pool and tries again. If the address we are looking for has been captured, then the script drops all other IP's and terminates.

The current version of this script works great to capture a single IP, but now we need it to capture several IP's. Here is the old single IP version:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Floating IP Reclaimer

################# CONFIG ##################
float="10.10.10.3"
tenantid="blah"
###########################################

# Start
clear
loop=true
if ! [ "$tenantid" = "$OS_TENANT_ID" ]; then
        echo "ERROR - Be sure you have sourced the proper tenant ID!"
else
        l=1
        while $loop; do
                printf "Floating IP Reclaimer\n\n"
                printf "Requesting address block...\n"
                for ((i=1;i<=5;i++));
                do
                        nova floating-ip-create floating-pool > /dev/null 2>&1
                done
                printf "Checking for matches...\n"
                nova floating-ip-list > /tmp/block
                while read garbage1 ip garbage2;
                do
                        if [ "$ip" != "$float" ]; then
                                printf "Releasing $ip\n"
                                nova floating-ip-delete "$ip" > /dev/null 2>&1
                        else
                                loop=false
                        fi
                done < <(tail -n +4 /tmp/block | head -n -1)
                printf "\nFloating IP blocks searched: "$l
                l=$((l+1))
                clear
        done
        printf "\nFloating IP reclaimed!\n\n"
fi
```

Thank you everyone for the help. I'm working on a solution as we speak. Unfortunately, sometimes I don't work too well under pressure.

Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't removing the `loop=false` get you a long way to your goal? Good luck.

Comment: There needs to be checks in place to recognize and keep the desired IPs and delete the rest. Also there must be a way to kill the script once the desired addresses are collected.

Comment: Anyone else able to help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size (it hasn't been tested).  I know it's not bash, but it should get the job done

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,time
import novaclient.client as nvclient

class FloatingIpManager():

    def __init__(self,desired_addresses=[],sleep=5):
        self.ips = desired_addresses
        self.nova = get_nova_client()
        self.sleep = sleep

    def get_nova_client(self,env=os.environ):
        d = {}
        d['username'] = env['username']
        d['api_key'] = env['password']
        d['auth_url'] = env['auth_url']
        d['project_id'] = env['tenant_name']
        return nvclient.Client('2',**d)

    def get_float(self,address=None,pool=None):
        while True:
            try:
                flip = self.nova.floating_ips.create(pool)
                if flip.ip in self.ips or address == None:
                    return True
                else:
                    self.release_float(flip)
            except Exception as e:
                print e
            time.sleep(self.sleep)


    def release_float(self,flip):
        return self.nova.floating_ips.delete(flip)

    def reclaim_all(self,addresses=None):
        if addresses == None:
            addresses = self.ips
        for i in self.ips:
            get_float(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nova = get_nova_client()
    reclaimer = FloatingIpManager(['192.168.100.1'])
    reclaimer.reclaim_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bash answer.  Call it with the IP's you want as arguments, like "reclaimer 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3"

```
#!/bin/bash
# Floating IP Reclaimer

################# CONFIG ##################
#float="10.10.10.3"
tenantid="blah"
###########################################

# Start
clear
loop=true
let count=$#-1
if ! [ "$tenantid" = "$OS_TENANT_ID" ]; then
        echo "ERROR - Be sure you have sourced the proper tenant ID!"
else
        l=1
        while $loop; do
                printf "Floating IP Reclaimer\n\n"
                printf "Requesting address block...\n"
                for ((i=1;i<=5;i++));
                do
                        nova floating-ip-create floating-pool > /dev/null 2>&1
                done
                printf "Checking for matches...\n"
                nova floating-ip-list > /tmp/block
                while read garbage1 ip garbage2;
                do
                        for float in $@; do
                                if [ "$ip" != "$float" ]; then
                                        printf "Releasing $ip\n"
                                        found=false
                                else
                                        let i=i+1
                                        continue 2
                                fi
                        done
                        nova floating-ip-delete "$ip" > /dev/null 2>&1
                done < <(tail -n +4 /tmp/block | head -n -1)
                printf "\nFloating IP blocks searched: "$l
                l=$((l+1))
                clear
                if [ i -eq count ]; then
                        loop=false
                fi
        done
        printf "\nFloating IP reclaimed!\n\n"
fi
```

Comment: I love this idea and I am trying to debug your code to make it work. I think there are a few bash syntax errors and also I dont see where you pull in arguments from when the user launches the script. Usually in bash its $1 $2 and so forth to get use the variables, but I'm not seeing you logic on how it applies inside the scrip. Also, I dont see how it can support large lists of inputs (ie multiple IPs) at this point. The input should be float.

Comment: Missing some $'s in <if [ i -eq count ]; then> too

Comment: Ah I think I see it now. A basic array is pulling each out. <for float in $@; do>

Comment: I take it all back haha. Looks like it is running so far. Need to do some more testing. Right now its trying to delete ips multiple times. ie if you enter five ips, it tries to delete all five, each five times. Or all six, each six times.

Comment: i made an edit that should fix it, even if it doesn't it shouldn't harm anything aside from making a few extra api calls.  You should probably put in a 'sleep 10' in an effort to minimize your impact on the platform as a whole.

Comment: there are a couple of conventions for getting command line arguments in this version.  You found the '$@' in the inner loop, that expands all of the arguments that the script was given starting with '$1'.  Near the top there is also 'let count=$#-1'.  That sets 'count' to the number of arguments given minus one since the script name is also counted so we can keep track of how many IP's we need to find and compare against the number found.

Comment: Sigh, go away pestering colleague 